# create 2 indexes on same column

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table with `geometry` column.

I have 2 indexes on this column:

```
create index idg1 on tbl using gist(geom)

create index idg2 on tbl using gist(st_geomfromewkb((geom)::bytea))
```

I have a lot of queries using the `geom` (`geometry`) field.

1. Which index is used ? (when and why)
2. If there are two indexes on same column (as I show here), can the `select queries` run slower than define just one index on column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of an index depends on how the index was defined, and how the query is invoked.  If you `SELECT <cols> FROM tbl WHERE geom = <some_value>`, then you will use the `idg1` index.  If you `SELECT <cols> FROM tabl WHERE st_geomfromewkb(geom) = <some_value>`, then you will use the `idg2` index.

A good way to know which index will be used for a particular query is to call the query with `EXPLAIN` (i.e., `EXPLAIN SELECT <cols> FROM tbl WHERE geom = <some_value>`) -- this will print out the query plan, which access methods, which indexes, which joins, etc. will be used.

For your question regarding performance, the `SELECT` queries *could* run slower because there are more indexes to consider in the *query planning* phase.  In terms of *executing* a given query plan, a `SELECT` query will not run slower because by then the query plan has been established and the decision of which index to use has been made.

You will certainly experience performance impact upon `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` of the table, as all indexes will need to be updated with respect to the changes in the table.  As such, there will be extra I/O activity on disk to propagate the changes, slowing down the database, especially at scale.

Answer (score 2):

Which index is used depends on the query.

Any query that has

```
WHERE geom && '...'::geometry
```

or

```
WHERE st_intersects(geom, '...'::geometry)
```

or similar will use the first index.

The second index will only be used for queries that have the expression `st_geomfromewkb((geom)::bytea)` in them.

This is completely useless: it converts the geometry to EWKB format and back. You should find and rewrite all queries that have this weird construct, then you should drop that index.

Having two indexes on a single column does not slow down your queries significantly (planning will take a bit longer, but I doubt if you can measure that). You will have a performance penalty for every data modification though, which will take almost twice as long as with a single index.